# Why was my question on Superuser changed to community-wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

It's a specific question with a specific answer.  I thought community-wiki was a ghetto for "Must-have super-awesome for $FOO" type questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has 10 answers. Any question on SuperUser with 10 or more answers is [automatically converted to Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6814/reduce-community-wiki-force-threshold-to-15-answers-on-superuser).

---

This rule seems to have changed in the past six years.  Here are
the four most recent Super User questions to accumulate 20 answers or more:

- [Easiest way to find out if user has either Windows 7 or Vista (through telephone support)?](https://superuser.com/q/401370/150988), March 2012, 21 answers
- [How do I upload huge files across the Internet without using P2P?](https://superuser.com/q/347819/150988), October 2011, 20 answers
- [How to find and remove “spicy” media files from my PC](https://superuser.com/q/331857/150988), September 2011, 25 answers
- [What are some options for transferring large files without using the Internet?](https://superuser.com/q/318653/150988), August 2011, 24 answers 
  (And, yes, one of the answers is [xkcd: File Transfer](http://xkcd.com/949).)

And none of these questions is CW. 
(A good way to see this is to query [is:q wiki:no answers:20](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20wiki%3ano%20answers%3a20) in one tab,
[is:q answers:20](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20answers%3a20) in another, sort both by “newest”,
and compare them side-by-side.)

**TL;DR**:  As recently as March 2012,
it was possible for a question on Super User to accumulate 20 or more answers
without being converted to Community Wiki.

<sup>(BTW, one of the above questions is by [“Scott”](https://superuser.com/users/96619/scott) — no relation.)</sup>

Comment: Well, that's sub-optimal.

Comment: I was also surprised when this happened to me first time.
Maybe it should be made more prominent in the FAQ.

Comment: The policy should be changed.  If the goal is to stop subjective discussion questions to community-wiki, subjective discussion questions should be move top community-wiki.  The author of a question has no control over how many wrong answers are given to his question.

Comment: Let me try that again.  If the goal is to move a class of questions to community-wiki, just do that.

Comment: @richardhoskins: I agree, the threshold of 10 seems a little harsh. I suggest letting Jeff know on the post I linked to earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6814/reduce-community-wiki-force-threshold-to-15-answers-on-superuser

Comment: @Kyle Cronin  Thanks, I just added to the discussion on that post.

Comment: That's dangerous, a malicious group of users could turn almost every post to wiki this way and not even pay the downvote penalties for bad answers.

Comment: Would any moderator, administrator, or developer care to document the current rules?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally checked the box? I don't see any edits to the question.

Comment: I did not.  And, I was received rep for the first 4 upvotes.